# Use command isn't getting triggered in discord economy system

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def use(ctx, *, item=None):

    if item == "watch" or "Watch":
        res = await sell_this(ctx.author, item, 1)

        if res[1] == 3:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have watch in your bag.")
            return
        responses = ["You looked at the watch and you realise it's 9:00PM and you have a date with a girl say COMING WAIT ME! before she kills you",
                     "You looked at the watch and you remmeber you have a meeting tomorrow and it's 2:00AM and then you realise it's a dream say  'WAKE UP WAKE UP' before you miss the interview",
                     "You looked at the watch and you realised it wasted 1 minute of your time say 'I LOVE TIME' before FBI comes raid your home", ]

        # VARiABLES
        users = await get_bank_data()
        user = ctx.author
        earnings = random.randrange(0, 6200)
        bad = random.randrange(0, 4200)

        if not res[0]:
            if res[1] == 1:
                await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
                return
            if res[1] == 2:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return
            if res[1] == 3:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return

        wat = random.choice(responses)
        await ctx.send(wat)

        def check(message):
            return message.author == ctx.author
        if wat == responses[0]:
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                if response.content == "COMING WAIT ME!":
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                    return await ctx.send(f"**Coming wait me {earnings} coins**")
                else:
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

                    return await ctx.send(f"**DIVORCED **! Your wife took {bad} coins from you. and she took your lovely kid **")
            except:
                await ctx.send(f"**DIVORCED **! Your wife took {bad} coins from you. and she took your lovely kid ")
                users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

                with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

        if wat == responses[1]:
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                if response.content == "WAKE UP WAKE UP":
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                    return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you didn't miss you meeting good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                else:
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                    return await ctx.send(f"**MISSED MEETING **! You missed your meeting and your wife took your 120 lovely kids and stole {bad} coins from you ")

            except:
                await ctx.send(f"**MISSED MEETING **! You missed your meeting and your wife took your 120 lovely kids and stole {bad} coins from you ")
                users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

                with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

        if wat == responses[2]:
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                if response.content == "I LOVE TIME":
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                    return await ctx.send(f"**Good job, FBI gave you {earnings} coins for being a good boy**")
                else:
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                    return await ctx.send(f"**JAiLED! **! FBI Jailed you and took {bad} coins from you. and you are now jailed**")

            except:
                await ctx.send(f"**JAiLED! **! FBI Jailed you and took {bad} coins from you. and you are now jailed**")
                users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

                with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

    if item == "lolipop" or "Lolipop":
        res = await sell_this(ctx.author, item, 1)

        if res[1] == 3:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have lolipop in your bag.")
            return
        questions = ["You used your lolipop and you enjoyed it",
                     "Your lolipop cried.", ]
        # VARiABLES
        users = await get_bank_data()
        user = ctx.author
        earnings = random.randrange(0, 6200)
        bad = random.randrange(0, 4200)

        if not res[0]:
            if res[1] == 1:
                await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
                return
            if res[1] == 2:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return
            if res[1] == 3:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return

        wat = random.choice(questions)
        return await ctx.send(wat)

    if item == "laptop" or "Laptop":
        res = await sell_this(ctx.author, item, 1)

        if res[1] == 3:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have watch in your bag.")
            return

        randomword = ["ytoueb", "poitsfy", "suimc", "ssa", "fcuk"]
        chuse = random.choice(randomword)
        mustchoose = ["You looked at the laptop and you saw there is a hot deal but you have 50/50 chance of winning it say 'START' to take the deal",
                      f"You looked at the watch and you realised it wasted 1 minute of your ugly face Complete the word to earn money or u lost money the word is '`{chuse}`'", ]

        # VARiABLES
        users = await get_bank_data()
        user = ctx.author
        earnings = random.randrange(0, 6200)
        bad = random.randrange(0, 4200)

        if not res[0]:
            if res[1] == 1:
                await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
                return
            if res[1] == 2:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return
            if res[1] == 3:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return

        chancebot = random.choice(range(0, 10))
        chanceme = random.choice(range(0, 10))
        wat = random.choice(mustchoose)
        await ctx.send(wat)

        def check(message):
            return message.author == ctx.author
        if wat == mustchoose[0]:
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                if response.content == "START":
                    if chancebot > chanceme:
                        lostembed = discord.Embed(
                            title="**You LOST**", colour=discord.Color.red())
                        lostembed.add_field(
                            name=f"Your chance:", value=f"`{chanceme}`")
                        lostembed.add_field(
                            name=f"My chance:", value=f"`{chanceme}`")
                        await ctx.send(embed=lostembed)
                        await ctx.send(f"You lost {earnings} coins :(")
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= earnings
                    if chanceme > chancebot:
                        wonembed = discord.Embed(
                            title="**You WON!**", colour=discord.Color.green())
                        wonembed.add_field(
                            name=f"Your chance:", value=f"`{chanceme}`")
                        wonembed.add_field(
                            name=f"My chance:", value=f"`{chanceme}`")
                        await ctx.send(embed=wonembed)
                        await ctx.send(f"You WON {earnings} coins LESH GOOOO")
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                else:
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                    return await ctx.send(f"**Wrong... :(( lost {bad} for participating**")
            except:
                await ctx.send(f"**Time is out you lost {bad} coins for participating**")
                users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

                with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

        if wat == mustchoose[1]:
            if chuse == randomword[0]:
                try:
                    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
                    if response.content == "youtube":
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                        return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you guessed the word good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                    else:
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                        return await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")

                except:
                    await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

            if chuse == randomword[1]:
                try:
                    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
                    if response.content == "spotify":
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                        return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you guessed the word good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                    else:
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                        return await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")

                except:
                    await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

            if chuse == randomword[2]:
                try:
                    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
                    if response.content == "music":
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                        return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you guessed the word good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                    else:
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                        return await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")

                except:
                    await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

            if chuse == randomword[3]:
                try:
                    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                    if response.content == "ass":
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                        return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you guessed the word good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                    else:
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                        return await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")

                except:
                    await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

            if chuse == randomword[4]:
                try:
                    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=8)
                    if response.content == "fuck":
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
                        return await ctx.send(f"**AMAZING JOB you guessed the word good job here take {earnings} coins :))**")
                    else:
                        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                        return await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")

                except:
                    await ctx.send(f"**WRONG WORD **! Very very bad job.. i will steal {bad} coins from you :P")
                    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad
                    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
                        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```

ALright so this code is basically to use an item and it works but it keeps sending watch questions even if i say *use laptop so like if i say *use laptop it will first send a watch question then lolipop question i think then a laptop question how to fix it?
Everything is appreciated
and again i just wanna make it so it can work <3

Comment: Try instead `if item.lower() == "watch":` or `if item == "watch" or item == "Watch"` as the way you used `or` is incorrect.

Comment: yeah, a non-empty string clause actually reads as an always True statement from a python truthiness perspective.  So when you say  `if item == "laptop" or "Laptop"` it's the same as saying `if item == "laptop" or True` ; it _always_ evaulates to True

Comment: Thank you @lemonhead and @ Bagle For the help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lemonhead mentioned in his comment

> a non-empty string clause actually reads as an always True statement from a python truthiness perspective. So when you say `if item == "laptop" or "Laptop"` it's the same as saying `if item == "laptop" or True` ; it always evaulates to True

The correct way would be `if item == "watch" or item == "Watch"`, but there are a few other ways to do it:

`.lower()` converts a string to all lowercase, `"WaTch"` -> `"watch"`

```py
if item.lower() == "watch":
```

---

if you have multiple options like "laptop" and "notebook", `if item.lower() == "laptop" or item.lower() == "notebook"` would get super long.

instead you can check if the item is `in` a list

```py
if item.lower() in ["laptop", "notebook"]:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for everything without you and @lemonhead help i wouldn't be able to do this thank you so much from my heart <3